# Create ORDER through REST Api return error 500 (post SUPEE-6788)

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, rest-api, supee-6788, create-order

I'm working with Magento CE 1.7.0.2. 
I've deployed SUPEE-6788 security patch and related 3rd party extension compliant patches on my test and preproduction environment.

I went successfully across an exhaustive process checklist until my last test: order creation with REST Api.

The product read operations are working fine with GET method on both test and preprod environments.

But the problem happens when I try to create an ORDER with POST method.
The order is not created and empty response returned by the webservice.
I receive the following status Code in my Firefox REST client: 500 Internal Server Error
Note: Same operation is working fine on my test environment.

No script error is returned, even with activating developer mode and error_reporting.

I decided to start a "hard debug session" with adding some logs on different steps (only on my preprod environment scripts).

At the end, my debug session brought me to the _runCallbacks method from Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction class.
The call_user_func() from line 106 is just blocked without throwing any Exception or error.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: `

I am using REST Api to create product, order with magento. I could successfully list products and orders, create products but unable to create orders. Kindly guide me \how could I create order through rest. 
` by **Sneha Maheshwari**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some heavy investigations, I've found the cause.

It was related to a 3rd party extension compatibility patch for SUPEE-6788.
This patch was pushed to the preprod environment only and not on both.